# React Native running app on device without server

Tags: ios, react-native

Its unbelievable how bad the documentation is for React Native, they just put as little as possible for everything. I've already managed to run my app using option 1 but option 2 is even more unclear: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html

I don't know there's no example of the terminal command react-native bundle in full so I know what is actually required there. For example --entry-file `<path>` what path? The whole path from my hard drive root to this folder, or just the file itself? --bundle-output....? What the hell do I need to put for that? I don't know why they need to make it so damn unclear.

I'm surprised there's no other resources online that give the instructions more clearly. I guess that's why there aren't so many React Native apps on the app store.

Comment: This is the question I ended up on after trying to do this for 5 hours. They made this even worse now with the Expo stuff, which are cool features but very poorly explained.

Answer (score 12):

I hope you also find that this is a much easier approach. In the example below, my app was named `BleMobileApp`. Feel free to change it to your app's name.

### RUN APP ON DEVICE WITHOUT DEBUG SERVER

1. Duplicate the main deployment target and name it `BleMobileApp-Deploy`.
2. Make sure to REMOVE the `DEBUG=1` flag in `BleMobileApp-Deply`'s `Build settings` (Do not touch the original target `BleMobileApp`!)

[image: Cloned Target]

3. Add a `New Run Script Phase` to `BleMobileApp-Deploy`'s Build phases and paste following command:

`yes | cp -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/main.jsbundle $SRCROOT/main.jsbundle`

[image]

That's it!

### (OPTIONAL) In case you would like to MINIFY the JS Bundle!

1. Edit file `./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` like below (Line 43~47)

[image]
2. Change the default run script like below (For `BleMobileApp-Deploy` target):

`export NODE_BINARY=node
FORCE_MINIFYING=true ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh`

This should do the trick for you.

Happy coding!

Comment: it is still not autonomous, after turning off the computer the app crashed and after Turing the computer back an I had the error: Lost connection to the debugger on “iPhone von XYZ”.

Answer (score 10):

From React Native Docs:

Configure release scheme Building an app for distribution in the App Store requires using the Release scheme in Xcode. Apps built for Release will automatically disable the in-app Developer menu, which will prevent your users from inadvertently accessing the menu in production. It will also bundle the JavaScript locally, so you can put the app on a device and test whilst not connected to the computer.

To configure your app to be built using the Release scheme, go to Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme. Select the Run tab in the sidebar, then set the Build Configuration dropdown to Release.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done from the terminal:

`react-native run-ios --device "My iPhone" --configuration Release`

Answer (score 3):

the best way i could find,
just follow the step bellow

- Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme
- Select the Run tab in the sidebar
- Build Configuration dropdown to `Release`

sometimes metro bundle starts, may be its bug in IOS but you can close it

Please see the attached screenshot
[image: Please see the attached screenshot]